Having problems while trying to trigger Clerk webhook in NextJS - errors 400 and 500
I was trying to sync my mongoDB database with clerk using webhooks, and create user based on my Clerk sign up. I successfully deployed my app to Vercel, and used the deployed URL to create Endpoint in Clerk, got the webhook secret from clerk and pasted it in my .env.local file. I have also disabled Vercel authentication in project settings, so that's not something that causes the error.
app/api/webhook/route.ts
 /* eslint-disable */
    import { Webhook } from "svix";
    import { headers } from "next/headers";
    import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
    import { WebhookEvent } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

import { createUser, deleteUser, updateUser } from "@/lib/actions/user.action";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  // You can find this in the Clerk Dashboard -> Webhooks -> choose the endpoint

  // TODO: ADD YOUR WEBHOOK SECRET TO .ENV.LOCAL
  const WEBHOOK_SECRET = process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET;

  if (!WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
    throw new Error(
      "Please add WEBHOOK_SECRET from Clerk Dashboard to .env or .env.local"
    );
  }

  // Get the headers
  const headerPayload = headers();
  const svixId = headerPayload.get("svix-id");
  const svixTimestamp = headerPayload.get("svix-timestamp");
  const svixSignature = headerPayload.get("svix-signature");

  // If there are no headers, error out
  if (!svixId || !svixTimestamp || !svixSignature) {
    return new Response("Error occured -- no svix headers", {
      status: 400,
    });
  }

  // Get the body
  const payload = await req.json();
  const body = JSON.stringify(payload);

  // Create a new Svix instance with your secret.
  const wh = new Webhook(WEBHOOK_SECRET);

  let evt: WebhookEvent;

  // Verify the payload with the headers
  try {
    evt = wh.verify(body, {
      "svix-id": svixId,
      "svix-timestamp": svixTimestamp,
      "svix-signature": svixSignature,
    }) as WebhookEvent;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error verifying webhook:", err);
    return new Response("Error occured", {
      status: 400,
    });
  }

  const eventType = evt.type;

  if (eventType === "user.created") {
    try {
      const {
        id,
        email_addresses,
        image_url,
        username,
        first_name,
        last_name,
      } = evt.data;

      const mongoUser = await createUser({
        clerkId: id,
        name: `${first_name}${last_name ? ` ${last_name}` : ""}`,
        username: username!,
        email: email_addresses[0].email_address,
        picture: image_url,
      });
      console.log("User created successfully:", mongoUser);
      return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: mongoUser });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating user:", error);
      return new Response("Error occurred while creating user", {
        status: 500,
      });
    }
  }

  if (eventType === "user.updated") {
    try {
      const {
        id,
        email_addresses,
        image_url,
        username,
        first_name,
        last_name,
      } = evt.data;

      const mongoUser = await updateUser({
        clerkId: id,
        updateData: {
          name: `${first_name}${last_name ? ` ${last_name}` : ""}`,
          username: username!,
          email: email_addresses[0].email_address,
          picture: image_url,
        },
         path: `/profile/${id}`,
      });

      console.log("User updated successfully:", mongoUser);
      return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: mongoUser });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating user:", error);
      return new Response("Error occurred while updating user", {
        status: 500,
      });
    }
  }

  if (eventType === "user.deleted") {
    try {
      const { id } = evt.data;
      const deletedUser = await deleteUser({ clerkId: id! });
      console.log("User deleted successfully:", deletedUser);
      return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: deletedUser });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error deleting user:", error);
      return new Response("Error occurred while deleting user", {
        status: 500,
      });
    }
  }

  return new Response("", { status: 200 });
}

app/middleware.ts
import { clerkMiddleware, createRouteMatcher } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

const isProtectedRoute = createRouteMatcher(["/ask-question(.*)"]);

export default clerkMiddleware((auth, req) => {
  if (isProtectedRoute(req)) auth().protect();
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};

After I sign up on my localhost, I expected to trigger the user.created event, or after I change the profile photo, I expected to trigger the user.updated event, but seems like my webhook is not being called at all. None of my console.logs are working inside the function. Also, when I sign up on my localhost, my Clerk dashboard shows 500 error, and when I try to change the photo, it throws 400 error. Any suggestions on how to possibly fix this?
